# How can I inheritance an interface without abstract?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, error, inheritance

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "./IERC20.sol";

abstract contract Lock is IERC20 {

    string name;
    string symbol;
    uint8 decimals;
    uint256 totalSupply_;

    constructor(uint _unlockTime) payable {
        require(
            block.timestamp < _unlockTime,
            "Unlock time should be in the future"
        );

        name = "SABOOR";
        symbol = "SAB";
        decimals = 5;
        totalSupply_ = 1000 * 1e5;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns(uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get if you try to compile without the `abstract` keyword actually tells you exactly what you need to do: you can't have a non-abstract contract which doesn't implement all of the function from the interface.

Since you are implementing interface `IERC20`, you have to explicitly implement all of the functions declared in that interface. Marking your contract as `abstract` circumvents that requirement, but you can't deploy abstract contracts.

Did you possibly mean to inherit the actual implementation of the interface, named `ERC20`? That way you don't have to implement the functionality yourself. So your contract declaration would be something like `contract Lock is ERC20`. Remember also to import the right contract.

If you don't have the ERC20 implementation, you can either get it from somewhere (for example OpenZeppelin) or then implement it yourself.